# Can a hacker access the data in my first request even if SSL cert is invalid?

Tags: ssl, https, security

This question is in context of web-services. If I invoke a web-service over SSL alongwith the required data for the service; I get an SSL error, if the SSL cert is invalid, and I wont make further requests. But what happened to the data I sent in the first request ? Will it be transmitted to the attacker ? Can he decrypt it ?

In a typical website this scenario hardly arises, as our request to server has hardly got any private data - once the server sends some form, only then we proceed with confidenial data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL/TLS is established before any data is sent. Consequently if there was an error, nothing is sent and your data is safe.